# Use utf8mb4 for database operations

Tags: plugin-development, mysql

the plugin I'm currently working on has to store user inputs which might contain 4 byte unicode characters like emojis. MySQL is not able to handle this with a utf-8 charset. It works if the charset of my tables is set to `utf8mb4` and if I add `'charset' => 'utf8mb4'` to `config/db.php`. Since the file `config/db.php` does not belong to my plugin, but to the installation of Craft itself, I'd like to not modify it.

Alternatively, I can convert the inputs with `StringHelper::encodeMb4()` but then I would have to do that at every place where something from the outside enters my tables.

Is there any pragmatic way of handling this?

Greetings Jus

Comment: Would it be an option to use your records `beforeSave` event to convert the string automatically when you do `$record->save()`?

Comment: Yes, that solves the issue. Thanks @RobinSchambach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crafts `ActiveRecord` has a function `beforeSave`

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    foreach ($this->fields() as $attribute) {
        $this->$attribute = Db::prepareValueForDb($this->$attribute);
    }

    // Prepare the values
    $now = Db::prepareDateForDb(new \DateTime());

    if ($this->getIsNewRecord()) {
        if ($this->hasAttribute('dateCreated')) {
            $this->dateCreated = $now;
        }

        if ($this->hasAttribute('uid')) {
            $this->uid = StringHelper::UUID();
        }
    }

    if ($this->hasAttribute('dateUpdated')) {
        $this->dateUpdated = $now;
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

You can overwrite this method and include your `StringHelper::encodeMb4()` into it so every time `$record->save()` is executed your string will be converted

Comment: Just make sure you convert them back before displaying them, via: `html_entity_decode($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`